# Working with webview and setUserAgent

Tags: android, webview

im current working with an android apps using webview, for some reason my apps would not return a mobile website even when i already use setUserAgent to mobile.

heres my code below. did i miss out something??

```
    setContentView(R.layout.post_layout);
    postView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.postView);
    postView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    WebSettings settings = postView.getSettings();
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    settings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; sdk Build/GRI34) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1");
    postView.loadUrl(url);
```

please help me out O_O...i been trying to work this out for a few days but there not alot of examples around :(...

Comment: I think you will have to set the userAgent using the WebView object, like postView.setUserAgentString("/Your Stuff"). Does that work for you ?

Comment: have you tried inspecting the HTTP headers to see what's actually being sent?

Comment: nope it dint work...u have to webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("/Your Stuff");

Comment: @fortran no i havent...i will look it up with HTTP headers and see..do you have any example..? sorry im newbie with android :(

Comment: I don't know either, I'm quite new to Android as well... Maybe it's easier to set up your own test server and hit it with your app to see what does it receive.